# Confused about bound parameters (Java Generics)

Tags: java, generics

I am going through the Java Generics tutorial, and I am a bit confused.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

It is the error message in this example that confuses me, I am not sure where inspect(10) comes from?

```
Box.java:21: <U>inspect(U) in Box<java.lang.Integer> cannot
  be applied to (java.lang.String)
                        integerBox.inspect("10");
                                  ^
1 error
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your class where this error, please

Comment: The Box is an Integerbox, so it expects an Integer value. `"10"` is a String! Use `10` (without the quotes around it) instead.

Comment: don't you mean `integerBox.inspect(10)` instead of `integerBox.inspect("10")`?

Comment: No, the whole code of your project.

Comment: Looks like a mistake in the tutorial and the error should say `integerBox.inspect("some text");`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone. I think John's answer is right? Because that's what it looks like to me but I am not an expert and hence I am asking here in case I am wrong.Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, why are people down arrowing my comment? I looked at the documentation, didn't understand something, so posted the question, provided the link to the documentation, provided the error, formatted it - so what have I done wrong that results in people down arrowing it?

Comment: unfortunately the community is harsh on newbies... sometimes people think they are too smart to help someone to improve his or her question, and downvote instead

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the problem is that you provide only a link to most of the relevant information (the `Box` class in this case). Instead you should include the information in the question itself, and have the link as reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, nandsito, that might just be the case.

Comment: John, the reference isn't detailed, and I thought it would just be better if someone read it than if I copied and pasted something in case I left out something of relevance. That's why I provided the link and didn't copy and paste. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Oracle documentation.
In my experience,
Oracle does not do a great job of editing their documentation.

In this case,
the error message
`integerBox.inspect("10");`
should actually read
`integerBox.inspect("some text");`